# How to run apache webpage from multiple directories in the home folder?

Tags: macos, apache, osx-mavericks

#### Web Directory Structure

```
~/Sites/
   ./subdomain1.site.com/
      ./cgi-bin/
   ./subdomain2.site.com/
      ./cgi-bin/
~/Remote/
   ./subdomain1.remote.com/
      ./cgi-bin/
   ./subdomain2.remote.com/
      ./cgi-bin/
```

#### /private/etc/apache2/users/< username >.httpd:

```
<Directory ~ "/Users/<username>/Remote/.*">
   Options Indexes Includes SymLinksIfOwnerMatch MultiViews
   AllowOverride None
   Order allow,deny
   Allow from all
</Directory>

<Directory ~ "/Users/<username>/Remote/.*/cgi-bin">
   AllowOverride None
   Options +ExecCGI
   Order allow,deny
   Allow from all
</Directory>

## Same thing as above, but using "Sites" instead of "Remote"

<Directory ~ "/Users/<username>/Sites/.*">
   Options Indexes Includes SymLinksIfOwnerMatch MultiViews
   AllowOverride None
   Order allow,deny
   Allow from all
</Directory>

<Directory ~ "/Users/<username>/Sites/.*/cgi-bin">
   AllowOverride None
   Options +ExecCGI
   Order allow,deny
   Allow from all
</Directory>
```

I copied Sites into Remote and restarted apache (`sudo apachectl restart`) -- also, tried stopping, then starting to be thorough.

- Directories contain the same permissions
- `index.html` loads for the Sites directory, but not Remote, despite being the same file
- URL looks like: `http://localhost/~<username>/<directory in Sites or Remote>/index.html`
- There's nothing in httpd.conf that enables `/apache2/users/<username>.httpd` config, it just seems to work for `Sites/`, but not `Remote/`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In OSX-Mavericks, httpd.conf includes /extra/httpd-userdir.conf by default.  This is where the "Sites" directory is being set.

Inside your setup, edit https-userdir.conf and add the line `UserDir Remote`.  This should enable both directories in your home folder.